# how to use equivalent of @Html.RouteLink in controller side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following used to generate a link in razor view:
`@Html.RouteLink(Model.LinkText, "ObjectFileDownload", new { fileId = Model.FileId }, new { @target = "_blank" })`

How can I do the same thing to generate a link on the c#/controller side? I would like to generate a link by passing in a link text, route, route value, and html values.

Answer (score 0):

If I've got the problem statement correctly, the easiest would be to use [HtmlHelper.GenerateLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.generatelink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var linkText = "your text here";
        var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "@target","_blank" },
        };
        var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary() {
            { "fileId", "Model.FileId" }
        };
        var generatedString = HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(Request.RequestContext, RouteTable.Routes, linkText, "Default", "ObjectFileDownload", "Home", routeValues, htmlAttributes);
            
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. It generates an empty link.

Comment: What's your environment like? I see you tagged it mvc4 - is your framework somewhat dated?

Comment: yes it is. Actually I was finally able to make it work using RouteLink method. Thank you.